# Importing / Exporting android library eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, import, export

I made a project as a library and now I want to export it in order to use it in others projects. Usually I just take the .jar generated but this time it doesn't work.
I included the .jar like this : 
Right click on the project > Build path > Configure build path > Add external jar's 
When I use my library, eclipse seems to recognize the classes in the .java files...

I think the problem come from the XML file because when I type the beginning of the class name, eclipse does not offer me the rest like it does with the native classes...

Also in the logcat this error has drawn my attention :

```
07-23 18:30:52.913: I/dalvikvm(4366): Failed resolving Lcom/example/test/MainActivity; interface 1000 'Lcom/omaflak/pulltorefresh/PullToRefresh$OnStartRefreshListener;'
```

Someone to help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android -> check the "Is Library" box. Now your project can be referenced in other projects when you specify so in the build path.

Another thing you could do is right click-> export, and choose JAR file from the wizard.
Using this method only pulls the classes though. It doesn't seem to pull any layouts/XML